# Nginx rewrite rule: add trailing slash before question mark

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

In Nginx, how do I add trailing slash before question mark in rewrite rule?

I have succeeded with adding slashes to the end of the URL. A follows:

```
http://test/xx --> http://test/xx/
```

But I can't implement adding trailing slash before the question mark. As Follows:

```
http://test/xx?id=2 --> http://test/xx/?id=2
```

I've tried the following:

```
server {

  listen 34044;

  # add trailing slash to url end
  rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

  # add trailing slash before question mark
  rewrite "^(.*)([^/]{1})\?(.*)$" $1$2/?$3 permanent;

  location / {
    ...
  }
}
```

But it doesn't add slash before question mark.

I think, I have a bug in the second regex, but I can't see it. Please help

Comment: The `?` marks the start of the query string which is not part of the normalized URI used in `location` and `rewrite` directives. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details. So any trailing `/` you rewrite, is always just before the `?` anyway.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand, thanks a lot! Answering my own question .. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After @richard-smith comment I understood that all I need is a single regex as below:

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

It works as I need: adds trailing slash to all URLS, including trailing slashes before '?' sign. And it doesn't break the resource links, such as https://my-site/styles.css .